# An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native

Tags: react-native

I want create new app with react native with react-native init  but I get error.

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
node: v12.9.0
npm: 6.10.2
yarn: 1.17.3

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you followed the react-native docs on how to get started?

Comment: Please give us the full error. The title of your question isn't quite suited for that.